# Appending a url term in Lucee

Tags: url-pattern

I would like to add a url-pattern in Lucee 5.x (Tomcat) when visiting a specific url folder a particular script name will be appended at the end of this url folder. For example when i type `http://localhost:8888/myApp/*`, the browser will be redirected to `http://localhost:8888/myApp/hello.cfm/*`.

I tried to add the term `/myApp/hello.cfm/*` in url-pattern of Tomcat config/web.xml, but unfortunately there is no redirection to the appropriate web address. Any idea would be convenient to me !

Regards